# Обновлённый текст выходит за экран

Tags: android, textview

**Условия:** Есть приложение с возможностью скачивать текст из облачного хранилища и демонстрировать его в `TextView`.

`TextView` расположено внизу экрана, вплотную к его краю.

**Проблема:** Если скачанный текст имеет, допустим, 3 строки, а текст демонстрирующийся до скачивания имел 2 строки, то третья строка нового текста оказывается за границей экрана (т.е. её не видно). Однако если перезапустить `Activity`, то `TextView` становится выше и текст виден полностью.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать, чтобы текст выравнивался по нижнему краю `TextView`? Или может быть есть какие-то альтернативные способы решения проблемы?

`android:gravity="bottom"` *- не сработало*

Comment: wrapcontent не помогает?

Comment: во-первых где расположен textview? точнее в чем? параметры этого контейнера? дайте больше инфы и приложите код, а не просто слова.

Comment: @TimurVI , сработало! Гениально))
Спасибо.